# readline() method does not work properly in my code

Tags: python, data-science

I have been working on decode problem.
I think that my function named decode works properly.(whole codes below)
However, I do not think readline() method does not work properly.
Where should I put `print(decode(line))` line??

Whole code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def decode(encoded_str):
    decoded_str = ''
    for char in encoded_str:

        decoded_str += chr(ord(char)-1)
    return decoded_str

print(decode('Hp Jsjti')) #print Go Irish

f=open('data/secret_message.txt','r')
# read and process the file one line at a time 
while True:
    line = f.readline()

    if line =='':
        break
print(decode(line))
f.close()
```

I tried to replace the line some times, but it did not show up anythig.

Comment: Suraj, I appreciate your editing.

Comment: Please follow [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to properly format your code blocks.

Comment: Put it inside the loop, right after `line = f.readline()`

Comment: Just indent your `print` and you should be fine.  It needs to be part of the loop.

Comment: Have you tried e.g. `print(repr(line))` just before the `if`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the `line` variable outside the `while` loop so it will return undefined and will not print anything.

Consider printing `line` variable within `while` loop:

```
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    print(decode(line)) # Decoding each line after reading it

    if line === '': # Also consider `===` instead of `==` read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons
        break
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Appreciate your help! It helps!!

Comment: There isn't `===` operator in Python.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example how you can read the file and decode the lines:

1.) Use `with` to open the file (that way, you don't have to call `file.close` explicitely

2.) Don't use `file.readline()`, iterate over the file object directly to get the lines.

3.) in `decode()` function, I've added special case for spaces `" "`

```py
def decode(encoded_str):
    decoded_str = []
    for char in encoded_str:
        if char == " ":
            decoded_str.append(char)
        else:
            decoded_str.append(chr(ord(char) - 1))

    return "".join(decoded_str)


with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()  # strip whitespaces from the line
        if line == "":
            continue  # skip empty lines
        print(decode(line))
```

Answer (score 3):

You iterate through the file looking for an empty string, then exit the loop once you have found an empty string. At best, you are going to end up with no output because the result will be an empty string from your iteration.

You probably want something more like this:

```
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    print(decode(line))


    if line =='':
        break
f.close()
```

Or even better:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    print(decode(line))
```

Comment: Appreciate your help! It helps!! –

Answer (score 1):

The `line` variable is valid in the `while` block only.

Just indent your `print(decode(line))`